# Mean difference between MATLAB and Excel

Tags: matlab, mean

I wrote a function that calculates the mean price of the last 15 mins of the trading day. In the attached excel file I get a mean of 55.23 but my function in MATLAB returns 55.32. I've been messing with this all day, and cannot figure out the answer for the difference. Can anyone tell me why the means are different in excel and MATLAB? Thank you.

```
function last15MinsOfDay=last15MinsOfDay(time,price)
% last15MinsOfDay takes the average of prices between 3:45 and 4:00.


timeStr=cellstr(datestr(time));
timeDbl=datevec(timeStr);
times=and(timeDbl(:,4)==14,timeDbl(:,5)>=46)+and(timeDbl(:,4)==15,timeDbl(:,5)==0);
priceIdx=find(times);
z=find(fwdshift(1,priceIdx)~=priceIdx+1);
z=[1; z];
mu=zeros(length(z),1);
for i = 1:length(z)-1;
    mu(i)=mean(price(priceIdx(z(i):z(i+1))));
end
last15MinsOfDay=mu;
```

[Excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mei20va6tjtisoz/testmean.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Does this line: `times=and(timeDbl(:,4)==14,timeDbl(:,5)>=46)+and(timeDbl(:,4)==15,timeDbl(:,5)==0);` need to be `times=and(timeDbl(:,4)==15,timeDbl(:,5)>=46)+and(timeDbl(:,4)==16,timeDbl(:,5)==0);` instead?  Difference is one does 14:46 though 15:00 and the other does 15:46 through 16:00.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the times are in CST. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The correct mean is 55.236 in your data. I'm not sure exactly what you're intending in the lines after the `priceIdx` line, but in MATLAB simply:

```
mean(price(priceIdx))
```

where `priceIdx` is a vector of the indices of the items you want to include should be what you need.